# Running Python on Jenkins for Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, jenkins

I am trying to execute python scripts (preferably python3) on mac.

Install Type: Brew

Python type: python3, anaconda and shining pandas installed.

Jenkins Ver: 2.60

Solutions tried: Jenkins shell, Python Plugin and executing script inline.

Issue:

> File "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins6919163542921297892.sh", line 6, in 
>       import urllib.request
>   ImportError: No module named request

and

> /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins7507623026196765310.sh: line 3:
>   python3: command not found

I have made some progress but Jenkins fails to pick up all the imported modules. I think the best step is to run Jenkins as my log on user - but I don't know how to do that.

For ubuntu there are solutions to change jenkins user here /etc/sysconfig/jenkins but this path doesn't exist for MAC. Also I am not sure what other steps are required.

Comment: Consider using a virtual environment and this jenkins plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ShiningPanda+Plugin

Comment: Are the modules in the site-packages of your mac?

Comment: @surfer190 I am already using ShiningPanda - and pointed to my install /Users/myname/anaconda/bin/python still getting same issues

Comment: Unfortunately the question is too broad as the topic is quite broad. Try getting a virtual environment setup locally for the project.

Comment: I have a virtual env already set up for the project, have tried multiple variations. Are you aware of any useful Jenkins/Python documentation?